# Which of "chafing at the bit" or "chomping at the bit" is more accepted/proper?

Tags: idioms, american-english, popular-refrains

I've used "chafing at the bit" for quite some time, but have also heard "chomping at the bit" as a way to indicate impatience, etc. Which of these two is the more "proper" or accepted variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chafing%20at%20the%20bit%2Cchomping%20at%20the%20bit%2Cchamping%20at%20the%20bit&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchafing%20at%20the%20bit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchomping%20at%20the%20bit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchamping%20at%20the%20bit%3B%2Cc0) shows a  wider use of *champing/chomping  at the bit*, probably indicating that they are  the more appropriate ones.

[be champing/chomping at the bit  also be chafing at the bit](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+chomping+at+the+bit)

> - to be very keen to start an activity or to go somewhere.
>
>   By the time he arrived to pick us up we were champing at the bit with impatience. I'm not sure if he's ready for extra responsibility yet, but he's chafing at the bit.

Source: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+chomping+at+the+bit

Comment: If you extend that NGram to 2008 you find *chomping* is now more common that both the others put together in Google's indexed books. And according to my [GoogleFight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=champing+at+the+bit&word2=chomping+at+the+bit), *chomping at the bit* is now over ten times more common than *champing* on the Internet at large. It's amazing how quickly some usages can change, particularly when you bear in mind that the vast majority of those "new" speakers have little or no knowledge of the real-world situation leading to the idiomatic usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - as far as you know, does Google-Fight make a distinction between BrE and AmE, or is it just a general use of the expression in all websites?

Comment: AFAIK GoogleFight has no mechanism for distinguishing BrE/AmE. [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chomping+at+the+bit%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cchomping+at+the+bit%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchomping%20at%20the%20bit%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchomping%20at%20the%20bit%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggest to me that ***chomping*** is almost exclusively AmE (there are probably enough "misclassifications" in NGrams to account for all the supposedly BrE instances, even if that overstates the case! :).

Answer (score 4):

The origin of this idiom comes from the habit of some horses to chew on the metal bit attached to their reins while impatient or anxious. I've always used and always heard the "chomping at the bit" version, and it seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: I would use 'champing' not 'chomping' - a quick google shows there's a big world of argument out there about which it should be, if you can be bothered to argue about such things! I think 'champ' is the older word but that doesn't mean it's more 'correct' - languages change. There's a N. Irish meal/dish called 'champ', presumably after the way it was eaten.

Comment: I've always used *champing* myself, but I knew plenty of others preferred *chafing*. What surprises me is how popular *chomping* has become in recent decades. It barely existed 50 years ago, but it's now [the most common version according to NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chafing+at+the+bit%2Cchomping+at+the+bit%2Cchamping+at+the+bit&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchafing%20at%20the%20bit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchomping%20at%20the%20bit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchamping%20at%20the%20bit%3B%2Cc0). And even more so on Google Internet.

Comment: I've never heard 'chafing' at the bit before.

Comment: @Mynamite: I have no idea where I heard the "chafing" variant, but I've used it for some time. I only learned about "chomping" when a colleague asked me if that's what I meant. The seemingly older "champing" is a fascinating evolution of this idiom.

Comment: @brightmatrix I always assumed that *chafing* came from the idea that chomping/champing at a bit would cause chafing/irritation at [the location of] the bit. Of course, now that I say it out loud it sounds like pure rationalization on my part.

Answer (score 2):

They mean different things. "Champing at the bit" means impatience. "Chafing" at the bit" means disliking being under the control of someone/something.

Comment: Or boredom? Not as serious a crib-biting, but unhappy that *nothing* ever happened.

Answer (score 1):

The correct term is **champing at the bit**, not chomping.  As a verb, to champ means to bite or grind your teeth impatiently.  To chomp means to chew food noisily.

Champing at the bit refers to a horse that has been bridled and wants to run, but has to stand there while the rider gets ready.  The horse is signalling its impatience.

Answer (score 1):

John Ayto, *Oxford Dictionary of English Idioms*, third edition (2009) provides a single entry for "champ at the bit" and "chafe at the bit":

> **champ** (or **chafe**) **at the bit** be restlessly impatient, especially to start doing something. Champ at the bit is used literally of a spirited horse that tugs at the bit in its mouth in its eagerness to move.

*Cambridge International Dictionary of Idioms* (1998) likewise doesn't report any distinctions in the meaning of the different possible wordings:

> **be champing/chomping at the bit; be chafing at the bit** to be very keen to start an activity or to go somewhere [examples omitted]

Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* (1997) has an entry only for "champ at the bit":

> **champ at the bit** Show impatience at being held back or delayed, [example omitted]. This term transfers the action of a horse that impatiently bites th bit in its mouth to human behavior. {Mid-1600s}

An Ngram chart comparing the frequency of "champing at the bit" (blue line), "chomping at the bit" (red line), and "chafing at the bit (green line) in published writing over the period 1850–2005 shows considerable change in their frequency of use over the past century:

[image]

The primarily American form "chomping at the bit" was the last of the three wordings to appear, but it seems to have caught up in popularity with "champing at the bit" since the mid-1990s. "Chafing at the bit" has been considerably less common than the other two since the late 1980s.

Answer (score 0):

It's 'champing at the bit.'Authority is David Niven using this expression in 'The Guns of Navarone'.

Comment: David Niven. An explanation and/or a reference would be great.

Comment: This means a wasted 2-hours watching a 1950's 'Intrepid Band of Men on  Desperate Mission against Impossible Odds'movie.

Comment: While I'm tediously researching 'The Guns of Navarone' script you'll have to settle for Ross Jack's statement. Ross Jack, as you know, is the manager of Elgin City FC in Scotland. Elgin FC, says Jack, expanded their schedule to two game a week because a scheduled game with QPR was called because of a frozen pitch. Jack: 'The players are champing at the bit, so it's all systems go.' This story is from The Northern Scot newspaper, 06/05/2011.

Answer (score 0):

The week of October 26, 2015, Los Angeles Dodgers announcer Vin Scully said he was "chafing at the bit" for his return in the 2016 baseball season.  (SportsNetLA)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question: which version is *more* accepted?  One usage instance doesn't tell us much.

Comment: You seem to be referring to the same incident that ScottFromWyoming brings up in a separate answer. Unfortunately, like his response, yours is much closer to a comment than to an answer. Please consider elaborating on your response to tie it to the larger question of whether "chafing at the bit" or "chomping [or _champing_] at the bit" is the more accepted or proper variant.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard chaffing and champing used since the 1950's, and increasingly chomping at the bit since sometime in the 80's, and assumed it was a mistake by Gen-X'ers and later Gen-Y'ers as either a mishearing or as an induced illiteracy from years of not listening very well.

Answer (score 0):

Chafe is to be rubbed raw or irritated, and champ is to chew or bite down.  So while nowdays champ, chomp, and chafe at the bit are used to express eagerness or impatience, whenever I had read or heard the terms as a child, chafe at the bit was meant to indicate dislike or irritation at being held back or under someone elses command, and champ at the bit was used to indicate eagerness to move forward or go ahead with something.

The more common usage is chomp in the US, but that is likely due to limited exposure to the other terms..not necessarily which is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Champ is the original term,
Chomp largely replaced it as a more easily identified word,
chafe is the logical result of the other two

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Answers need to be substantial and need to be supported by citation to demonstrate that they are not merely expressions of opinion.